# Multiple foreign keys to same table in EF

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table that has two foreign keys to the same table...
When I'm trying to add or update Entity Framework model it generates something like this:

```
    public virtual SystemDefinition SystemDefinition { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemDefinition SystemDefinition1 { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemDefinition SystemDefinition2 { get; set; }
```

Everything works fine for me but tbh I hate default object names e.g. "SystemDefinition1" and "SystemDefinition2" etc... I can rename it and it also will work fine, but when i try to update entity model(or delete and add it again), it still generates this default names.
(Also if I "Run custom tool")... Could you please explain, how do I avoid renaming?
Where and how can I set default names for objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you must use exactly same column name of 1st table which is foreign key to the 2 nd table

```
public virtual SystemDefinition 1stTableColumnName { get; set; }
```